# Issue with file upload to a shared location

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.Net MVC 4 . I am trying upload a file to a shared location to which I have access. After publishing my application to IIS, I came to know that I need handle impersonation at code level. I referred [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158) link to implement ASP.net impersonation. It works in my local development server whereas in IIS it doesn't .

Here is my code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadDoc(string fileName)
    {
        string destination="sharedPath";

        if (ImpersonateUser("Test", "test", "Test")) // tested with my own credentials
        {       
            System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, destination);    
            return Json(destination);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Error");
        }  
    }
```

I have also set the impersonate identity to true in my web.config file.

Comment: what type of error are you getting, forbidden, permission denied? can you elaborate more on your issue?

Comment: I tried surrounding my code with try catch but it doesn't throw any error. FYI , I tried running my application on custom server (my ip address where my application is deployed to ,the localhost) to debug from VS . It runs with no issue validating my credentials.